# How does Laravel Artisan serve built-in server without blocking the terminal?

Tags: php, laravel, server, shell-exec, laravel-artisan

I tried emulating artisan's serve command by using `shell_exec()`. But somehow once it boots up the terminal is blocked. I also tried running it in background and storing the output to a variable:

`shell_exec("php -S localhost:8000 &"); // runs the server but blocks the terminal`

`$result = shell_exec("php -S localhost:8000 &> /dev/null 2>&1");
echo $result;   // this does not show anything`

The idea is so that I can create  custom messages once php server is up.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tired this!

> "This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the
>   program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution
>   failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the
>   program exit code is required."

[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)